# How do you retrieve data from Firebase that has been manually entered?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a new iOS app for a lacrosse team. I've manually added a `registrationCode` into my Firebase database.

I've tried getting a reference to the database and then using the `.observe` method to get the value but it crashes.

My latest code attempt:

```
    let rootRef = Database.database().reference().child("groove-lacrosse")
    rootRef.observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
        print(snapshot.value as Any)
    })
```

What's the correct way, programmatically, to retrieve Firebase data that was manually entered?

The image is the Firebase entry
[image]

Comment: What is the crash saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `groove-lacrosse` is the name of your database, in which case you don't need to specify that anywhere.

Instead you can just read the registration code directly and then print its value:

```
let rootRef = Database.database().reference().child("registrationCode")
rootRef.observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
    print(snapshot.value as Any)
})
```

Comment: Interesting.  I had tried that and assumed that it did not work.    
        let rootRef = Database.database().reference().child("registrationCode")
        rootRef.observe(.value, with: {snapshot in
            print(snapshot.value as Any)
        })

        print("placeholder")  I added a print placeholder statement and I see the snapsot print after that. I believe I wasn't giving it enough time. Thanks for your help.